# Expressing ratios verbally

Tags: terminology, ratio

$\frac{1}{3}$ of angels are demons, and $\frac{2}{3}$ are good angels.

Does this mean there are:

1. $2$ good angels for every $1$ bad angel
   (∵ $2+1=3$ total angels, but this ratio seems to be $1:2$ not $2:3$)

or

2. $3$ good angels for every $2$ bad angels?

Comment: That means (1), not (2). "One third" says one out of every three angels is a demon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the fractions like so:

$\frac{1}{3}$ and $\frac{2}{3}$  and multiply them by $3$ so you get:

$1$ (bad angel) and $2$ (good angels)

This means there are 2 good angels for every bad angel.